# Detect client has disconnected from jetty server (using continuations)

Tags: java, jetty, continuations, disconnect

I am using jetty continuations and I was wondering if I can detect that the client has disconnected(closed connection to jetty server) from the server.

Thanks,
Alfred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a cleaner way to do it but, when you call continuation.resume() you will get an IllegalStateException if the client has disconnected. Just catch that exception.